# Find equivalence classes of x ~ y : <=> x-y ∈ Z

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations, congruences

The equivalence relation is:

$$X=\mathbb{R}$$
$$x∼y:⇔x−y∈\mathbb{Z}$$
I proved the relation properties but how can I find the equivalence classes?

Also I was wondering whether the equivalence relation above is the same as the following?

$$n∈\mathbb{N}$$
$$x∼y:⇔n|x−y$$

Does this help?
Is it related to congruence?
Also, I think x and y must have the same decimal expansion, does this help?

**EDIT**: Thank you all for your help.

Comment: You pretty much said the answer yourself: $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ is in the same equivalence class if their 'decimal part' is the same: for instance, $0.5\sim 1.5 \sim 2.5 \sim 3.5 \sim 4.5 \sim \cdots$ etc

Comment: Can I somehow write that down in a formal way for all x in R?

Comment: A complete set of representatives is made up of the points in $[0,1)$.

Comment: Just find a set $X$ which contains every decimal part just once; the equivalence classes are then uniquely given as $[x]=x+\mathbb Z$ for $x\in X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think someone posted an answer before but it seems it is deleted now. Anyway consider $[x]$ the equivalence class for some $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

If $y\in [x]$ then $x\sim y$ so $y-x\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $y\in x+\mathbb{Z}$.

Conversely if $y\in x+\mathbb{Z}$ then $y-x\in \mathbb{Z}$ so $y\sim x$ and $y\in [x]$

So $[x]\subseteq x+\mathbb{Z} \subseteq [x] \implies [x]=x+\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: This makes sense to me, thanks! With [x]=x+Z the decimal part must always be the same.